# How to make a list with nested loops

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to make a list of all the competitions with their competitors (riders).
Competitions are saved in `tbl_GAME` and all the competitors in `tblRider`.

I tried the code below but it didn't work. Is the problem that I put a `while` loop in a `while` loop?

```
<?php
include_once('class/Competition.class.php');

$c = new Competition();
$comp = $c->getAllCompetitions();

 while ($game = $comp->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "
        <table id='showAll'>
            <tr>
                <td>Rider
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>rank</td><td>naam</td></tr>
                        "; 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `tblRider` WHERE `ContestId` ='".$game['ContestID']."' AND '".$game['type']."'=1 AND `GroupID`='".$game['GroupID']."'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    while($rider =mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<tr><td>1</td><td>".$rider['RiderFirstname']." ".$rider['RiderLastname']."</td></tr>";
    } 
    echo "
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Run1
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Judge1</td><td>Judge2</td><td>Judge3</td><td>Judge4</td><td>Judge5</td><td>Judge6</td><td>Totaal</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>45</td><td>67</td><td>80</td><td>96</td><td>44</td><td>33</td><td>234</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Run2
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Judge1</td><td>Judge2</td><td>Judge3</td><td>Judge4</td><td>Judge5</td><td>Judge6</td><td>Totaal</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>45</td><td>67</td><td>80</td><td>96</td><td>44</td><td>33</td><td>234</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Overall
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>leeg</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>30</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
        }   
?>
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? Doesn't it produce anything? The wrong output? The right output in the wrong way?

Comment: You're directly interpolating unquoted values in a SQL query, which is extremely insecure; if this code is accessible via the web, someone will soon use it to compromise your server. Investigate the PHP PDO package, especially its prepared statement capabilities, with all haste.

Comment: It that something that I can do with real_escape_string?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your database schema it's difficult to say for sure, but based on your code it appears you would be better off performing a SQL join rather than a separate database SELECT query for each "game" row.

Each database query is computationally expensive.  If you tbl_GAME query returns 1000 rows, and your tblRider queries on average return 1000 rows, you will perform 1001 separate queries (returning 1,000,000 total database rows).  Consolidating this into a single SQL Join could get it down to one total SQL query, which is going to be faster (probably much faster).

A SQL join would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblRider, tbl_Game 
WHERE tblRider.ContestId = tbl_Game.ContestID  
  AND tbl_Game.type=1 
  AND tblRider.GroupID = tbl_Game.GroupID
```

If you are nesting your queries because you are trying to group thing based on game then you could just use an ORDER BY clause to make sure each rider is basically grouped by game and for each rider record you pull up compare it to the previous rider record.  If the GroupID or ContestID changed then render your new grouping header.

I will also echo Aaron Miller's comment and highly recommend you look at using [PHP PDO](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and use [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) and bind your variables/parameters.

[Here is a article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) on getting started with PDO.

Comment: I used your query and added group by, but then I get a table with the contest and one competitor. I am trying to get a table with all the competitors of that competition. I don't understand how I can do that without a loop.

Comment: Do you mean your mysql_fetch_array call is only returning one result?  What does your full SELECT statement look like with the GROUP BY?  No matter what you will need to have one loop statement to loop through your mysql fetch statement, I was just trying to remove the need for nesting.

I'm not sure why you would need GROUP BY, since that will aggregate your results and is typically used, for example, if you needed to get a count of riders for each contest. Above I suggested using ORDER BY, which sorts the results in your mysql_fetch_array call, not GROUP BY.

Comment: Also, do you know the contestID and groupID before hand?  If so you could inject that directly into your SQL query for tblRider (or, if you are getting those variables from a URL or user input, use parameter binding) and not use the join with tbl_Game at all.

Also, what does "$comp->fetch_assoc()" actually do?  Is there a SQL query in the "fetch_assoc" function?  And in your original code in the question are you planning on using "$game" for anything else in that loop?  If not you actually probably don't even need the join.

Comment: So nom I'm using order by (my mistake), but this gives not al lot of difference.
For "$comp = $c->getAllCompetitions();
 while ($game = $comp->fetch_assoc()) { ..." --> this is the query that goes with it:
   SELECT * FROM tblRider, tbl_GAME 
   WHERE tblRider.ContestId = tbl_GAME.ContestID  
   AND tblRider.GroupID = tbl_GAME.GroupID
   order by GameID

I do know contestID and GroupId before hand